# hide div when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery issue, Kindly see my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".toggle_container").show();

    $("h2.trigger").toggle(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
            }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
    });

    $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow,");
    });

});
```

My .toggle_container is shown always its good, But I want to close it first time, when page load. Can you please provide me any solution?
I dont want to use $(".toggle_container").hide(); function for this problem because when i click on href then .toggle_container should not hide, It should open.

Regards.

Comment: in which cases you want it to be shown and in which hidden?

Answer (score 16):

You can just add attribute

```
style="display:none"
```

to your element .toggle_container.

Then on first call of $(document).ready it will be shown.

**The full test example:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow,");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2 class="trigger">Toggle</h2>
  <div class="toggle_container" style="display:none">Container</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: there`s no $(".toggle_container").show(); on $(document).ready

Comment: I have applied .toggle_container{ display:none;} But this not works, If I applied .toggle_container{ display:none !important;} It works But it disable the toggle function. Can you please provide solution in Jquery? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Check out full test example in my answer.

Comment: check this: <html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow,");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2 class="trigger">Toggle</h2>
  <div class="toggle_container" style="display:none"><a href="default.html">Container</a></div>
</body>
</html> When I click on link, it should stay,toggle_container disappeard. Any solution?

Comment: You should put link outside of div.toggle_container if you want link to be visible always.

Answer (score 2):

remove the

```
$(".toggle_container").show();
```

from your `$(document).ready` function.

in html part add `style="display:none"` for the `toggle_container` `div`.

check the @HCK s reply. he is clearly mentioned it..

Answer (score 1):

Once the document gets loaded, a alert box will be prompted "page loaded".

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    alert('page loaded');  // alert to confirm the page is loaded    
    $('.divClassName').hide(); //enter the class or id of the particular html element which you wish to hide. 
});
```

Comment: Once the document gets loaded, a alert box will be prompted "page loaded"  enter the class or id of any particular element which needs to be hidden.
Note - alert box is to just show that page is loaded. request you to remove it.